# From XML to Blog post

Tags: xml, wordpress

I have an XML file and I would like that when I update the XML file, in automatic, I create a new post in Wordpress Blog in a pesonal server. Which way I should follow?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://if(function_exists('display_slideshow'))%7Bdisplay_slideshow($slideshow_name)%7D;) describes one users effort to create posts from xml.  WordPress also has a feature that allows you to post by email/xml-RPC.  Look under Settings->Writing in the admin section of your site.